# getting a TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable error

Tags: python

The line
rl=[ m(m*x)+b for x in xs]
is causing a "TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable' error
code

```
xs=np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], dtype=np.float64)
ys=np.array([5,4,6,5,6,7], dtype=np.float64)

def best_fit_slope_and_b(xs, ys):
    top= ( s.mean(xs) * s.mean(ys) ) - s.mean(xs*ys)
    m=top/(  (s.mean(xs)*s.mean(xs))-s.mean(xs*xs)   )
    b=s.mean(ys)-m*s.mean(xs)
    return m,b

m,b = best_fit_slope_and_b(xs, ys)
print(m,b )

# below line causses error
rl=[ m(m*x)+b for x in xs]
```

Comment: Is `m` callable? You're trying to call it with `m(m*x)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you write the multiplication.

`m(m*x)` is not the same as `m*(m*x)`, because `m()` is interpreted as a function when is probably a number. Further more, if thats the case you could also do:

`m**2 * x`